# Debugging AWS API Gateway Mapping Template Serialization Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, velocity

So, I have a mapping template and I'm posting some JSON to the API Gateway. Sometimes successfully, but as I make my mapping template more complex I keep running into the error response:

```
{
    "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"
}
```

I'm not looking for a specific answer to fix my specific mapping template, just to know where (if it exists) I can see more info on that serialisation error.

Comment: you can enable logging on API gateway, have you tried